# how to achieve CheckBox Checked and Unchecked event in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I have manufacturer name with checkbox, when i checked manufacturer then by checked event i want to display all product from that manufacturer,...

how to achieve CheckBox Checked and Unchecked event in MVC 3

Answer (score 1):

> how to achieve CheckBox Checked and Unchecked event in MVC 3

Suppose you have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacturerCheckbox" />
```

You can capture it's "Checked and Unchecked event" by:

```
$("#manufacturerCheckbox").click(function () {            
    alert($(this).is(':checked') 
        ? 'checkbox is checked' 
        : 'checkbox is unchecked');
});
```